# Below code work in oracle 11g but oracle 12c release 1 give ora-00600 error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Below code work in oracle 11g but oracle 12c release 1 give ora-00600 error. How can I make it database version independence?

```
DECLARE
  lxml xmltype;
    l_tag varchar2(30);
begin
  lxml :=
  xmltype('<responseObject>
             <error>That is not a valid request</error>
             <errorCode>A11</errorCode>
             <value>A</value>
           </responseObject>
           ');
 l_tag := 'responseObject/*';
  FOR test IN (
    select tag,
           VALUE
    FROM   xmltable(l_tag
             passing lxml
             columns
               tag VARCHAR2(128) path 'name()',
               VALUE VARCHAR2(128) path '.'
           ) t
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(test.tag || ' - ' || test.value);
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```

Comment: ORA-00600 is usually *bad news* which reads as "contact Oracle Support" as it means that there's an internal bug. **However**, I tried your code on 12c (12.2.0.1.0) and it works OK. Which version do you use? Did you check My Oracle Support?

Comment: ORA-00600 is Oracle's standard error message for unhandled side-effects i.e. bugs in its code. The standard advice is to contact Oracle Support. If you don't have a Support contract you may be out of luck. Such bugs are often specific to **exact version** of database and/or operating system. Post full details of the message and your environment and possibly somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: what is the o/p of the below SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter
         WHERE name = 'compatible';

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in patch 26281022 which is due to bug 25437089 and 25967544. More details are available in this link

[Doc ID 2279533.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=92610871992532&id=2279533.1&_adf.ctrl-state=zubn7foe2_147)

Comment: please accept the answer if your issue is resolved by it